# How to calculate an average between certain cells in a column that corespond to cells in a different column?

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble explaining exactly what I need, it'll be easier if I just give an example. Please keep in mind I'm not a programmer of any sorts, I'm just working on getting together some statistic data for my job.

```
Column 1    Column 2
   1            D
   2            A
   3            D
   4            D
   5            A
```

What I need is to calculate an average between the numbers belonging to column 1 that correspond to cells belong to column 2 which have the value "D". I imagine the easiest way would be to just sort the whole table alphabetically around column 2, but I'm not allowed to make any changes to the table. I hope I got my point across clearly enough, thank you in advance!

Comment: If the answer helped you please remember to mark it as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click the green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [AVERAGEIF() Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642):

```
=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"D",A:A)
```